# How to SQL DELETE a python generated list

Tags: python, sql

I am not strong in SQL at all, and I tried searching around on how to convert my Python list into a proper format SQL. But I can only seem to convert into single separated tuples, instead of having all strings in one tuple.

```py
Users_to_del = ['Aske Meyer', 'UserT', 'BUser', 'test3']
del_string1 = ', '.join([f"(\'{name}\')" for name in users_to_del])
sql =  'DELETE FROM users_from_group WHERE name_of IN %s;' % del_string1
print(sql)
cur.execute(sql)
```

The SQL query:

```sql
DELETE FROM users_from_group WHERE name_of IN ('Aske Meyer'), ('UserT'), ('BUser'), ('test3');
```

What I want to achieve:

```sql
DELETE FROM users_from_group WHERE name_of IN ('Aske Meyer', 'UserT', 'BUser', 'test3');
```

Comment: Don't concatenate input to generate SQL strings. What if one of those values contained `O'Reily`? Or `'); Drop Table Students; --` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the brackets out of the join:

```
del_string1 = ', '.join([f"\'{name}\'" for name in users_to_del])
sql =  'DELETE FROM users_from_group WHERE name_of IN ( %s );' % del_string1
```

Comment: What happens if one of those values is `'); drop table users; #` ? Or `O'Reily` ? That's how SQL injection problems occur

Comment: you're right, here of course we have to assume that the values are already cleaned. if you are interested in how to prevent sql injections, you might want to open a new question